# Why can't my project build on two different systems

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am working on an Android app in Unity. I have it setup and running on my desktop pc. Whenever I click on build everything works fine.

Unfortunately I can't take my desktop pc with me, so I work on a laptop when I'm not at home. The problem is: With the exact same settings in the project, the game does not compile on my laptop due to problems with the target-sdk version.

I'm not an android developer so I am not aware of what I have to do to fix this error on my laptop.

The error states (summed up):

> Unable to merge Android manifests
>
> target-sdk-version for plugin is 25, you use 23

I know I can change that somewhere in Unity. Changing the API-Level didn't help I get the same error even in the newest version. I checked on the fact that my desktop pc and my laptop have the same API Levels available. I updated Android Studio to the newest version.

I also made sure that there is no android manifest in my project which states that I need a target-sdk-version of 24 or 25, just one that says min-version 14, target-version 19.

As I said it does compile without complains on my first system but on the second one it fails and I don't know why. I hope anyone can tell me what to do to fix this problem.

You can see my settings below

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you done "Invalidate caches / Restart" in file tab of android studio.

in unity:
Go to Edit => Preferences. In the Preferences window go to GI Cache Tab. And then click clean cache.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/732312/how-to-clear-cache-for-unity.html

Comment: How do I get there? I do not use Android Studio directly, so there is no project or similar, I merely use it for the sdk that comes with it.